# Hard top radiator hose soft bottom hose

Tags: overheating, radiator, xterra

I've been investigating my friends Xterra overheating issue and noticed that after idling for a while the top radiator hoses was rock hard while the bottom one was much softer. Could this be an Indication of a clogged radiator?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this post, where checking the radiator was suggested to you. See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/67002/10976

Comment: Have you actually checked the radiator since I suggested it to you?